# Python TLS1.2 socket server

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I have an assignment to create a secure socket server using TLS version 1.1 or 1.2. I'm using python 3.4 (as that's the only version with native TLS 1.1/1.2 support). I've made a self-signed CA and signed both the client and the server. A snippet of the code is as follows:

In my server:

```
tls_server = ssl.wrap_socket(server, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, server_side=True, 
    keyfile='./server.key', certfile='./server.crt',
    ca_certs='./SigningCA/signing-ca.crt')
```

and in the client:

```
tls_client = ssl.wrap_socket(client, keyfile="./client.key", 
    certfile="./client.crt", ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, 
    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs='./SigningCA/signing-ca.crt')
```

The connection works fine, I get a request and response. But when I print out the results of the client or server cipher() method, I get the following:

```
('AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
```

which seems to indicate I'm still running TLSv1/SSLv3. Does anyone have some insight into this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you figure something out, please share. :)

Comment: How did you get it to accept ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 ?